# how to use a static vector inside a static function

Tags: c++, qt, static-members

I am try to use `vector<int> myVector2`, however, I have trouble it to use on a `static function (foo)`. I use Qt and here is the default code below:

```
   Mainwindow.h
---------------------------------------------------
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <QString>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    static std::vector<int> myVector2;
    static void foo();
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

};
```

.....

```
mainwindow.cpp
------------------------------
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    foo;

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::foo(){
    MainWindow::myVector2.push_back(3);

}
```

I just added `static std::vector<int> myVector2;
    static void foo();` to header and  `void MainWindow::foo(){
    MainWindow::myVector2.push_back(3); }` on the above code. when I compile it, I get such error:

```
mainwindow.o: In function `MainWindow::foo()':
mainwindow.cpp:(.text+0xe7): undefined reference to `MainWindow::myVector2'
mainwindow.cpp:(.text+0xee): undefined reference to `MainWindow::myVector2'
mainwindow.cpp:(.text+0x10e): undefined reference to `MainWindow::myVector2'
mainwindow.cpp:(.text+0x126): undefined reference to `MainWindow::myVector2'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [ddd] Error 1
14:46:36: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project ddd (kit: Desktop)
When executing step 'Make'
```

if I remove `static` before the vector and function, then it compiles fine but I want these two to be accessible directly.

How is it possible to fix the above code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add

```
std::vector<int> MainWindow::myVector2;
```

to mainwindow.cpp.

BTW:

This

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    foo;

}
```

probably should be:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    foo(); // <- note () here;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to mainwindow.cpp:

```
std::vector<int> MainWindow::myVector2;
```

When you declare `static myVector2` in `MainWindow` class, this is kind of forward declararion. You need to create the variable in one of .cpp file to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to *define* that vector, put this outside the class declaration in the implementation file (.cpp):

```
std::vector<int> MainWindow::myVector2;
```